# Vue-strap Carousel: How to select specific slide

Tags: vue.js, vue-strap

I have managed to create a carousel (slider) using Vue-strap carousel component with the following code:

```
<carousel>
        <slider  v-for="(photo,index) in photos"  :key="photo.sequenceID" >
            <img v-bind:src="'https://../photo/' + photo.photoFilename " >
        </slider>
</carousel>
```

Carousel is working. I also display thumbnails of images on the page. I want to select a specific slide when I click a thumbnail.

How can I display a specific slide in the carousle? Is there a function in Vue-strap carousle or slider that can displays specific slide if I pass the slide number?

Comment: There is no built in support for this. https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Carousel.vue

Comment: I see that there is a method indicatorClick that is used to select a specific slide when the indicator dot is clicked.  ` methods: {
      indicatorClick(index) {
        if (this.isAnimating || this.index === index) return false
        this.isAnimating = true
        this.index = index
      },`  I am new to Vue amd Vue-strap. If my carousel element has id "car", could you advise how to call the indicatorClick() method?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will display the slide fo the pictureID. It uses the indicatorClick() method of the carousel component. Here vm is the Vue object name.

```
vm.$children[0].indicatorClick(pictureID);
```

Comment: You might need to change $children[0] depending on the components you have in your Vue object.

Answer (score 1):

Late reply:

You can use the `navigateTo` prop as follows:
*template.vue > tamplate/transition*

```
<carousel
  :perPage="1"
  :navigateTo="carouselPosition"
  :navigationEnabled="true"
  :paginationEnabled="false">
  <slide>
    ...
  </slide>
</carousel>
```

`carouselPosition` should be stored as a prop:
*template.vue > export default {}*

```
data () {
  return {
    carouselPosition: null // OR 1
  }
}
```

Include the following on your thumbnail element:
*template.vue > component thumbnail*

```
v-on:click=";(carouselPosition = index)"
```

In this case the `index` value would be generated in a loop:
*template.vue > component loop*

```
v-for="(thumbnail, index) in yourData"
```

NOTE: [Nuxtjs](https://nuxtjs.org/) used in this example but it should easy to modify these examples to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

### Using `v-model`

See [Carousel documentation](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/carousel);

> Programmatically control which slide is showing via v-model (which binds to the value prop). Note, that slides are indexed starting at 0

```
<b-carousel
  id="image-carousel"
  controls
  indicators
  img-width="1024"
  img-height="480"
  v-model="currentSlide"
>
```

Inside my slide I use a `img` for every thumbnail. Upon click `currentSlide` is changed to the index of the thumbnail.

```
<img
  v-on:click="showImage(index)"
/>
```

store `currentSlide` in data:

```
data() {
  return {
    currentSlide: 0
  }
}
```

method for changing `currentSlide`

```
showImage (index) {
  this.currentSlide = index;
}
```

**Vue will update the value prop of the slider if the v-model reference is changed.**

Answer (score 0):

use `v-bind:data-slide-to="index"`

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" 
                 v-for="(image, index) in images" v-bind:key="index"
                 v-bind:data-slide-to="index"
                :class="{'active' : index===0}"></li>
</ol>
```